# Why is my HTML5 canvas drawing behaving this way?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm learning to use the HTML5 canvas, and I decided to animate the drawing of a circle:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KdpyVm

It starts correctly, by drawing from a point, and then completes the circle. But there's clearly a few fundemental things I don't understand.

1. Why does the arc appear bold initially when drawn, and then the line gets thinner 3/4 of way? Is it somehow redrawing over itself?
2. When the arc `endAngle` reaches 2PI, why does it not start over?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't clearing the entire canvas (only the top left portion), so the extra thickness in the lines are happening from the section of the canvas that is not getting cleared when the circle is being redrawn:

```
ctx.clearRect(0,0,600,600);
```

**http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wKaPgz**

Comment: You can also see this is being caused by the additional drawings by commenting the call to `requestAnimationFrame` within `draw`

Answer (score 1):

As Spencer Wieczorek said, you aren't clearing the whole canvas.

You should use the canvas' own width and height to clear the canvas.

Change:

```
var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
```

To:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas')
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
```

And then use the width and height like so...

```
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
```

This way, if you change the canvas size, the whole thing will still get cleared.